# Homogeneous in Variables Separables

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

**Problem:** Be $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$

(a)The equations of the form $x'=f(\frac{x}{t}), t\ne 0$ are called homogeneous. Show that the change of variables x = yt transforms homogeneous equations into equations of separable variables.

(b)Solve the equation $$x'=\frac{x+t}{t}, x(1)=0$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$x'=\frac{x+t}{t}=\frac{x}{t}+1$$ 
Now let $y=\frac{x}{t} \rightarrow x=yt$

Then by chainrule $x'=\frac{dy}{dt}t+y$

Substituting this gives $$\frac{dy}{dt}t+y=y+1$$ $$\frac{dy}{dt}t=1$$
Ill let you finish it from there.

EDIT:

For part (a) basically do the same process using the chain rule you get $$x'=\frac{dy}{dt}t+y$$

Substituting in for both gives,  $$x'=f(\frac{x}{t})$$ $$\frac{dy}{dt}t+y=f(\frac{yt}{t})$$ $$\frac{dy}{f(y)-y}=\frac{dt}{t}$$

Comment: Solve you part A?

Comment: Yeah just a sec ill edit.

Comment: hey man. How do I use the hypothesis of $x(1)=0$?

Comment: After you solve the differential equation for x in terms of t, plug in 0 for x and 1 for t and you then get an equation you can solve for your constant.