# Homogeneous in Variable Separables

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

1. Show that any homogeneous differential equation $ x' = f(\frac{x}{t})$ can be reduced to an equation equation with separable variables by means of the change of the unknown function $x=ty$.
2. Consider the differential equation
   $$M(t,x)dt+N(t,x)dx=0$$
   with $M(t,x)$ and $N(t,x)$ are homogeneous functions of the same degree. Show that this equation is homogeneous in the sense considered in the preceding problem.

This question is from Principle of Differential and Integral Equations by C.Corduneanu

1. Let $y=\frac{x}{t}$. Then $x=yt$, so $x'=y+ty'$. Thus,
   $$f(y)=y+ty' \Rightarrow f(y)-y=ty' \Rightarrow \frac{y'}{f(y)-y} = \frac{1}{t}. $$
   or same approach written [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2230185/homogeneous-in-variables-separables).
2. ( I don't know how to show this problem. )

Answer (score 1):

$$M(t,x)dt+N(t,x)dx=0$$
$$M(t,x)+N(t,x)x'=0$$
$M,N$ are homogeneous of the same degree...and $x=yt$
$$M(t,yt)+N(t,yt)(y't+y)=0$$
$$t^aM(1,y)+t^aN(1,y)(y't+y)=0$$
$$M(1,y)+N(1,y)(y't+y)=0$$
$$y't=-y-\dfrac {M(1,y)}{N(1,y)}$$
It's separable.
$$y't=g(y) \implies \dfrac {dy}{g(y)}=\dfrac {dt}{t}$$
You can also write it as:
$$y't+y=-\dfrac {M(1,y)}{N(1,y)}$$
$$x'=-\dfrac {M(1,x/t)}{N(1,x/t)}\implies x'(t)=f(x/t)$$
Since $x=yt$ and $x'=y't+y$.

---

$f$ is homogeneous of degree $n$ means:
$$ f(zx,zy) = z^nf(x,y) $$

Comment: You've shown that it is variable separable, how to show it that it is homogeneous?

Comment: @jiid this line shows that it's homogeneous $x'=-\dfrac {M(1,x/t)}{N(1,x/t)}\implies x'(t)=f(x/t)$ Because $x'=y't+y$

Comment: I showed that the DE is  homogeneous and separable ... @jiid